# Access values from multiple field forms as elements of one form

Tags: entities

I'm trying to create entities from my custom form. To do that, I created "Add more" button, where I'm dynamically adding new elements that I'm attaching fields to by using:

```
field_attach_form('myentity', $entity, $form['wrapper']['myentities'][$key]['fields'], $form_state);
```

I would like to create entities in submit callback with field values from those elements.

The problem is, that when I have a multiple elements, inputs for the same type of fields of different entities have the same "name" attribute (eg. `field_myfield[und][0][value]`), which means that I can access only the value from the field of the last entity in the submit callback, which means that I cannot fill my entity with proper values before saving. I tried to put '#tree' => TRUE up the form tree, and unset this value on field level, but it didn't change an input name, and "values" structure.

How can I have in my submit callback access to all of the field values, so I could use them for creating entities?

Comment: $form['wrapper']['myentities'][$key]['fields'] what is the $key variable here? Could you post a bit more context of what your form looks like? Normally setting the form['#tree'] to true should do the trick.

Comment: $key is a number, in submit handler I'm creating basic entity objects and adding them to array in $form_state `$form_state['myentities'][] = entity_create(...)`, and during ajax replacing, in my main form building function I'm iterating over this array and creating form elements for those entities with attaching fields.

Comment: Apperantly you have to use the #parents key to fix this, see the documentation on field_attach_form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the #parents variable as documented in the field_attach_form page. 
See [field_attach_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7)